# How do I partially suppress the command-line output of zip?

Tags: command-line, python, zip

The Background: I have a python script that generates a bunch of images (png format, minimum of several hundred), runs ffmpeg to turn them into a short video, and then puts all of the images into a zip archive so I can go back if I find any strange or interesting things where I want the individual frame.

The Issue: Originally the zip portion read as `zip -q -T -m output *.png` but that suppressed **all** the output, including the statement as to whether the file is ok. Is there a way to suppress the large number of `updating: Stars0053.png (deflated 5%)` without suppressing the output of the `-T` switch?

Comment: does adding this behind it work: |grep updating >/dev/null  ?

Comment: For some reason that's suppressing the `-T` output line as well. Is the >/dev/null maybe applying to the output of both zip and grep?

Comment: Maybe the ``zipfile`` module from Python's standard lib can do what you want (it has a ``testzip()`` method).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
zip -q -T -m output *.png  && echo "success" || echo "failure"
```

should work too, alternative to the solution, given in the comments.

It works like this: If the first commmand (zip ...) succeeds, the following combination with && can succeed too and is performed. But if the first part fails, then the whole combination will fail, and the &&-part is skipped, but an or-combination is successfull if one of both is successful, so the ||-part is performed.

You aren't interested in the combined result (true/false), but in the side-effect: a status feedback.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty much exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: -q
       --quiet
              Quiet mode; eliminate informational messages and comment  prompts.   (Use‐
              ful, for example, in shell scripts and background tasks).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use pythons own zip library:

http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html